# Excel Formula to find the price based on industry and number of transactions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to determine the price for my input table which has the specific industry type and the average monthly transactions based on the reference table 1 which has the price for different industries (these represent the A tier prices) and the reference table 2 which classifies the price tier based on the average monthly transactions..Reference table 1 has the price for pricing tier A for all the industries .. The price for tier B is calculated as 90% of price of Tier A price; the price for tier C is calculated as 90% of price of Tier B price and so on...Can you please help here...

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Thanks,
Arun

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post the tables as html instead of screenshots, so we don't have to manually type your data to get your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Office 365 Excel with the new LET() function and XLookup, I would add a factor calculation to the Reference2 table that shows the multiplication factor for tiers B to F, starting with 1 for A and multiplying that by 0.9 for B, and so on.

Then you can use Let() to look up the Tier letter for the line item transaction figure, use that tier letter to look up the factor in the Reference2 table and look up the price from the industry table. Multiply the two and that's your desired value.

```
=LET(myTier,XLOOKUP([@[avg transactions]],Reference2[minimum],Reference2[Tier],"not found",-1),
XLOOKUP([@Industry],Reference1[Industry],Reference1[price])*XLOOKUP(myTier,Reference2[Tier],Reference2[factor]))
```

[image]

If you don't have the Let() function in your arsenal, this will be more complex and would need a separate helper column to store the looked up tier letter.

Comment: Thank you so much @teylyn!..Appreciate your help!